# External SMTP server in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

Do you guys know any easy way to set up Magento 2 to use external SMTP server?

We currently use MailGun.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for setup external smtp server?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. @Rajkumar.E

Comment: follow this  link http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-mail-using-your-smtp-detail/  this is use full for you...